# How to prevent prom printing if href only contains #

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I am using [jQuery-printPage-plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin).

I have a print button

```
<a href="#" id="printbutton" onclick="checkprintbutton();"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> </a>
```

I am initialising the printPage plugin

```
$('#printbutton').printPage({  message:"Printing ticket for:<span></span>" });
```

I have list of bookings and when I click on a booking the url (href attribute) for the print button changes.

```
function trBookingClick(id)
{ 
    $("#printbutton").attr("href","{{ $pageUrl }}/print/"+id);
}
```

If I click on print button without selecting a booking, I show an error message.

```
    function checkprintbutton() {
    var href =  $("#printbutton").attr("href"); 
    if (href=="#") {
    notyMessageError('No booking selected! Select a booking and try again.');
    $('#printbutton').printPage({  beforeCallback: function() {return false; }, message:"Printing ticket for:<span></span>" }); 
    }
```

The problem is that it's initialising the printPage plugin even though there is no link for the print button. How can I prevent printPage from initialising if href attribute contains hashtag?

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bhvLs3q5/1/).

Thank you very much in advance. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You have your .printPage() call in the the same if statement, if you dont want that called there move it

Comment: @PatrickEvans is right, add `else` statement after you call `notyMessageError`.

Comment: I used beforecallback in there and tried to stop it from initialising but it didn't work. I commented that line. here is the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/bhvLs3q5/2/ the thing is once it's initialised it doesn't check if it has a link or not it just tries to print a blank page.

Comment: @Walk if I do   this ```if (href=="#") {
    alert('No booking selected! Select a booking and try again.');
    } else { $('#printbutton').printPage({ message:"Printing ticket for:<span></span>" }); }``` everytime I click the print button it initialises PrintPage. If I want to print 3 different bookings on the 3rd click, it initialises PrintPage  for the 3rd time. so it initialises it over and over again. In the status bar I see```waiting http://...``` 3 times after the 3rd request it prints the booking. short of all printpage needs to initialise once before other functions not on click.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Johnny I misunderstood your problem, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this line:

```
$('#printbutton').printPage({  message:"Printing ticket" });
```

specifying that you don't want your element to have `href` set to `#`:

```
$('#printbutton:not([href="#"])').printPage({  message:"Printing ticket" });
```

**UPDATE:**

This should work if you dinamically change your href:

Edit this:

```
this.on("click",
    function(){  loadPrintDocument(this, pluginOptions); return false;
});
```

to

```
this.on("click",
    function(){ 
        if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
            alert('No booking selected! Select a booking and try again.');
            return false;
        }
        loadPrintDocument(this, pluginOptions); return false;  });
```

And you can remove your `checkprintbutton()` function completely.

Comment: It worked! I cannot believe that the solution was so simple. I spent hours and hours trying to make this work. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Johnny actually, looking at your code, it seems like you're setting `href` attribute dinamically? If that's the case it might not work. However, check an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Walk, Yes I am setting href attribute dinamically but once I select a booking the href  attribute doesn't change back to #... The url remains same until another booking is clicked (i.e. /print/1548). Once printpage is initialised it doesn't matter what the link is. I didn't quite understand the purpose of this function. I am testing at the moment but if I encounter any problem I will try this code.

Comment: I am not sure how ```$('#printbutton:not([href="#"])').printPage()``` worked previously. But I accidentally deleted the code and couldn't make it work again. So, I used your updated code. I initilised printpage ```$('#printbutton').printPage()``` like this and used ```function(){ 
        if ($("#printbutton").attr('href') == '#') {
            notyMessageError('No booking selected! Select a booking and try again.'); 
            return false;
        }
        loadPrintDocument(this, pluginOptions); return false;  });``` and it's working like charm. Cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

`printPage` should be in `else` if there are no bookings selected:

```
if(href == '#') {
    notyMessageError('No booking selected! Select a booking and try again.');
} else {
    $('#printbutton').printPage({  beforeCallback: function() {return false; }, message:"Printing ticket for:<span></span>" });
}
```